# как в reactjs передать dispatch в класс?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Всем привет у меня есть простой класс в reactjs

```
class A{
  //TODO
}
```

Мне нужно внутри этого класса вызвать функцию dispatch
Как мне ее подключить?

Comment: Какие данные и куда вы хотите диспатчить?

Comment: У меня есть функция которая добавлена через import мне ее надо запустить

Comment: Создать метод класса и в нем вызвать, или если это компонент реакта (extends Component) то вызвать его в методе render()

Comment: У меня нет там метода render - это просто класс в файле

Answer (score 0):

импортируете функцию connect:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
```

Делаете export:

```
export default connect()(A)
```

Тогда внутри A у вас в props будет функция dispatch